# May I interpret confidence levels as confidence intervals in r?

Tags: r, confidence-interval

If I got values of lower .CL (**confidence level**) and upper .CL for **a** category of A factor, each o.206, 0.245 and

for **b** category of A factor, each 0.215 and 0.256 in R, can/may I so interpret?

: **confidence Interval** of a is [0.206, 0.245] and of b is [0.215, 0.256]?

- Edited

| A | emmean | SE | df | lower.CL | upper.CL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 0.21 | 0.0009 | 52 | 0.206 | 0.245 |
| b | 0.205 | 0.0009 | 52 | 0.215 | 0.256 |

Comment: Please try to explain your question and provide a code sample. Also, not that a CI should be noted along its confidence level.

Comment: I agree with @Spätzle on the suggestion to provide a code sample. However, to my best knowledge, the values in your example refer to confidence intervals. Confidence levels refer to the probability with which the estimation of the location of a effect estimate is also true for the population i.e., usually set at 90%, 95%, or 99%. HTH

Comment: Thanks then lower & upper. CL is confidence interval? I thought CL means confidence level!! and what is the code sample? I thought the table examples is a code sample...

Comment: Lower CL and upper CL are the confidence limits, i.e the limits of the confidence interval.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: If you had displayed the annotations that emmeans added below that output, you'd have seen that it states that the confidence *level* used is 0.95. That suggests that the values shown in the table above are not confidence levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be explicit: Suppose you have the (fictitious) data sampled using R below:

```
set.seed(2021)
x = rnorm(20, 50, 7)
summary(x);  length(x);  sd(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  36.54   49.86   52.48   52.76   60.42   62.11 
[1] 20        # sample size
[1] 7.621391  # sample standard deviation
```

A boxplot and a stripchart (dotplot) of the data are shown below:

```
par(mfrow = c(2,1))
 boxplot(x, col="skyblue2", horizontal=T)
 stripchart(x, pch=20)
  abline(v=mean(x), col="red")
par(mfrow = c(1,1))
```

[image]

```
t.test(x, mu = 55)

        One Sample t-test

data:  x
t = -1.3151, df = 19, p-value = 0.2041
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 55
95 percent confidence interval:
 49.19194 56.32578
sample estimates:
mean of x 
 52.75886
```

Then (because this is simulated data) we know population mean is $\mu = 50,$
sample mean is $52.76,$ which is not significantly different from hypothetical mean $\mu_0 = 55.$ A 95% CI for $\mu$ is $(49.19, 56.33).$ which is centered at $\bar X = 52.76$ and contains $\mu_0 = 55.$

In a real application you would never know that $\mu =50,$ exactly. The best point estimate is $\hat \mu = \bar X = 52.76$ and we can be 95% confident
that $\mu$ is in interval $(49.19, 56.33).$

A narrower 90% confidence interval is $(49.81, 55.71).$

```
t.test(x, conf.lev=.90)$conf.int
[1] 49.81208 55.70564
attr(,"conf.level")
[1] 0.9

And a wider 99% CI is $(47.88, 57,63).$

t.test(x, conf.lev=.99)$conf.int
[1] 47.88327 57.63445
attr(,"conf.level")
[1] 0.99
```

To consolidate these relationships, you should look at the formula in
your text or class notes for a one-sample t.test and use the summary
information printed above for $n, \bar X, S_x$ to make all three confidence intervals, 90%, 95%, and 00%.
Then check your hand computations with the results above from R.

Comment: Wow thank your for your detailed explanation and time :D confidence levels are just the number 90, 95 and 99?

Comment: Yes 90%,, 95%, 99%.

Comment: Super thanks!!!

Comment: Maybe you need to talk to a statistical consultant. There is more to statistics than running programs. You need to understand what it is you have.